# Missing Loading Image From Database Use Handler.ashx

Tags: asp.net, database, image

I use the Handler.ashx to get and display images from database.
But they didn't all display, only 100% after request few times.
I don't know how to solve.

Handler.ashx code:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.Request.QueryString["ImageID"] != null)
    {
        Byte[] bytes;
        string _strModelCode = context.Request.QueryString["ImageID"];
        try
        {
            bytes = ModelBLL.GetImage(_strModelCode);
        }
        catch
        {
            bytes = null;
        }
        context.Response.ContentType = "Image/jpg";
        if (bytes != null)
        {
            try
            {
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            }
            catch { }
        }
        context.Response.End();
        return;
    }
}
```

Image Loading Code:

```
foreach (GridViewRow _row in gridDispaly.Rows)
        {
            Image img = (Image)_row.FindControl("imgModel");
            img.ImageUrl = "../Handler.ashx?ImageID=" + _row.Cells[0].Text;
        }
```

Thank you!

[Error Loading Image From Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx4qp.png)

Comment: You have some catches there, but they're not reporting anything for you.  Basically, you're swallowing any possible error and not telling you about it in anyway.  Honestly, I would comment out the try/catches and see what error pops up, then fix any errors and put the try/catches back in. Additionally, see about logging any exception that you catch.

Comment: I removed all Catches, it is no error happen. But it still don't display 100% images!